# escape environment visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut/extension that moves the cursor outside an environmnet in VS code? for example, in LaTex when entering `$ 2+3=5 $`, I'd like a shortcut that will move the cursor after the second `$`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the [TabOut](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut&ssr=false#overview) extension, it's possible to modify which characters it tabs out off.
After installing the extension, look for the file `~/.vscode/extensions/albert.tabout-0.2.0/out/src/charactersToTabOutFrom.ts`, and add the characther that defines the environment. For example:

```
charArray.push(new CharacterSet_1.CharacterSet('$', '$'));
```